# proper statistical test to check differences

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have 3 replicas for a value in different individuals. Each of these values are ratios $ab$, and $a$ and $b$ are means from $n=20$ sample pool each. Thus there are 3 times each ratio $ab$ for each individual. When comparing for differences is student t-test correct?

```
                 1st sampling -   2nd         -   3rd         -   4th
individual 1  -  0.7164165213 -  0.6057539083 -  0.5242174359 -  0.7670756899
individual 2  -  0.6540839702 -  0.8140762612 -  0.6057645321 -  X
individual 3  -  0.611493629  -  0.7270260938 -  0.5255522645 -  0.9964242368
```

as said each sampling value comes from A/B, whereas A and B are means for treated and non treated for a given variable with n ranging from 15-25.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by comparing for differences?  In what regard exactly do you wish to look for differences?

Comment: sorry im not from a math background. I want to know if the number groups are statistically different. usually student t test is used, but i dont know if it is proper after having calculated the ratios from the raw means before. Also my n is small as i have 3 replicas

Comment: also the abolute numbers are rethe small: ranging from 0 - 1

Comment: do you have access to the values A and B? rather than combining into one number (ratio, which reduces your data) you can do a paired t-test or something similar

Comment: I'd say go with ANOVA and then do some post-hoc analysis with pairwise t-test or TukeyHSD - like here http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/110437/49130

Answer (score 1):

This question is not clear at all, or what the ratios mean. A sample code/structure of the data would be help provide proper context and definition of the problem.

Generally speaking, when you have more than two means to compare, you should not use the t-test because you are inflating your Type II error. If you want to know which pairs of means are statistically different from one another, you should be using a factorial design and the resulting ANOVA table.

Comment: A is the mean for control values and B is the mean for the treated for a given variable. There are 3 repetitions of the experiment thus there are 3x A values and 3x B values. within each repetition another variable which is A/B is calculated, thus having 3 A/B values. i repeated this for 2 different individuals and i want to know if there is a difference in the response to the treatment, thus i want to compare the mean (or whatever is correct) between A/B between each individual. the original A and B had samplings smaller than 25.

Comment: also A/B ratios have values smaller than 1.5 thus diferences are really small in absolute number terms

Comment: You should edit your initial question to include this information.

Comment: Your question says "ab" but now you are saying that you calculated "a/b", so I am still confused as to what you're after. As Jsk suggested, please edit your question to include this information. And since your data set is small, it would not hurt to include your data as well.

Comment: in the qustion it states "ab ratio". i initially put as a/b but the editor correcter this way